# What is the difference between an amorphous solid and glass?

Tags: crystal-structure, phase, materials, glass

They are both formed when a liquid is supercooled rapidly, no free energy, and they both have irregular structures. What defines a glass other than how it is amorphous, transparent, and has a glass transition state?

Answer (score 5):

While a glass is generally considered to be a supercooled, configurationally frozen liquid, not all amorphous solids are glasses. For example, amorphous silicon is a four-fold coordinated semiconducting solid, much like crystal silicon.  Liquid silicon is 8-12 fold coordinated with metallic bonding. Amorphous silicon has been shown to display a first-order phase transition to both the crystal and the liquid.

So, all glasses are amorphous solids, but not all amorphous solids are glasses.

Comment: So how can you tell the difference between glass and a supercooled liquid or any other amorphous solid?

Comment: The supercooled liquid will have an x-ray diffraction pattern similar to the liquid.  The amorphous solid may be different, and will be different if it is not a glass. Note above the difference in coordination number between metallic silicon and semiconducting crystal or amorphous. The first order phase transition from amorphous to crystal solids is shown in calorimetry.

Comment: While I am going to give this an upvote, I do object to "*glass is generally considered to be a supercooled, configurationally frozen liquid*" although I think it is technically (statistically) true, if a million people say a foolish thing it is still a foolish thing.

Comment: @A.K. - fair enough, and that could also be sub field specific. The sub field I was in some time ago (dealing with amorphous silicon amongst other materials) agreed on that distinction.

Comment: @A.K. when objecting to something it makes sense to explain in detail why one is objecting and the counter-reasoning if possible ;)

Comment: @Thomas The counterexample would be crosslinked polystyrene at RT. A glass, virtually undistinguishable from ordinary glassy PS, but cannot melt. Or any other rubbery substance below $T_g$.